# javaのclassファイルにバージョン情報を埋め込みたい

Tags: java, eclipse

windowsのdllファイルとかだと右クリックプロパティからバージョン番号を見れるものがありますが
あんな感じの情報をjavaのclassファイルに埋め込みたいです。
windowsとeclipseで開発してますがそのようなことは可能でしょうか。
可能ならやり方を教えてください。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javapコマンドでclassファイルを逆アセンブルする方法もあります．
windowsで動作確認していませんが，Linuxでは以下のように
コンパイル前のファイル名，クラス名，コンストラクタ，フィールド名，メソッド名が
が確認できます．

```
$ javap Hello.class
Compiled from "Hello.java"
class Hello {
  public static final java.lang.String VERSION;
  Hello();
  public void sayHello();
}
```

-vオプションを付けるとより詳細に表示されます．

```
$ javap -v Hello.class
...
  public static final java.lang.String VERSION;
    descriptor: Ljava/lang/String;
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC, ACC_FINAL
    ConstantValue: String 1.0.0
...
```

このように，定義した変数の値も確認できるので
(ここでは VERSION = "1.0.0" とした)
コンパイル前にjavaファイルにバージョン情報を埋め込むことで
javapコマンド経由で確認することもできます．

Comment: クラスを逆アセンブルというのは面白そうです。ちょっと手間ですが、イメージしていたものに割りと近いです。
ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

`.dll`ファイルに相当するのは`.class`でなく`.jar`ファイルになるかと思います。

JARファイルの仕様では`META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`ファイルに、[実装バージョン](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/technotes/guides/versioning/spec/versioning2.html#wp90468)を記述する[`Implementation-Version`セクション](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Main_Attributes)があります。
これが[DLLのバージョン情報](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AA%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9_(Windows)#%E7%A8%AE%E9%A1%9E)に近いものかと考えます。

JARファイルへのマニフェストファイル追加は[`jar`コマンド](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/7/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html)の`m`オプションで行えます。

あるいは、 `maven-jar-plugin` を利用するのであれば、[`addDefaultImplementationEntries`を`true`に設定](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/manifest.html)することでプロジェクトのバージョンを自動で`Specification-Vendor`に設定することも出来ます。

---

ただし、Javaプログラマに「何によってJARファイルのバージョン識別を行うか」という質問をしたとき、回答で最も多いのは(上記のような`MANIFEST.MF`のエントリによってではなく) **JARファイルのファイル名によって** 識別する、だろうと思われます。

Javaではバージョン管理対象となるようなJARファイルの生成には[Maven](https://maven.apache.org/)を使用するのが一般的で、これを利用してJARファイルを生成した場合、デフォルトでファイル名にバージョン番号が付与されます。

例えば[こちら](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22junit%22%20AND%20a%3A%22junit%22)ではJUnitのバージョンごとのファイルがダウンロードできますが("Download"の"jar"リンク)、バージョン`4.12`であれば`junit-4.12.jar`, バージョン`3.8.1`であれば`junit-3.8.1.jar`という名前になっているのが確認できるかと思います。

Maven形式のプロジェクトは、Eclipseなど一般的なJava用IDEで取り扱うことができます。

Comment: すいません、ちょっとわけあってjarではなくclassにバージョンを埋め込みたいのです。
サーバーの所定の場所にclassファイルをおいておくとフレームワークと連携して動く仕組みなのですが
そのclassファイルの中身を分かるようにしたいという目的なので。
ファイル名にバージョンを埋め込むのもちょっと厳しいです。

Answer (score 0):

1案目として考えられるのは、一般的なファイルシステムから標準的に取得できる情報(具体的には「ファイル作成日時」など)でバージョニングを行う方法です。
メリットは取り扱いが簡単なこと、デメリットは他のアプリケーション(圧縮展開ツールやファイル転送ツール)で意図せずとも情報が書き換えられてしまう可能性が有ること、でしょうか。
Javaでは [`BasicFileAttributeView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributeView.html) インタフェース経由などでread/writeできます([実装例](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26537_01/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html#basic))。

2案目として考えられるのは、([ファイルシステムがサポートしている](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15829683/4506703)のなら) ユーザー定義属性としてバージョニング情報を格納することです。
こちらは[`UserDefinedFileAttributeView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/UserDefinedFileAttributeView.html)インタフェース経由でread/writeします([実装例](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26537_01/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html#user))。
メリットは本来(すなわちバージョニング)のための情報として保持できること、デメリットは1案目より低いポータビリティでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

アノテーションを使うのはどうでしょう。

Version.java:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Version {
    String value();
}
```

Main.java:

```
@Version("1.0")
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class c = Main.class;
        Version v = (Version) c.getAnnotation(Version.class);
        System.out.println(v.value());
    }
}
```